# Upgrade to Mozilla Firefox 20 and Selenium IDE 2.0.0 - path for user-extensions.js has changed?

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide, user-extensions.js

I recently upgraded to firefox 20, and upgraded selenium IDE to 2.0.0

I have a custom "user-extensions.js" file that I usually put here:
C:\Users\skyn\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\1dj9c5sr.default\extensions{a6fd85ed-e919-4a43-a5af-8da18bda539f}\chrome\content\selenium-core\scripts

Only now, with Firefox 20, the directory structures have changed apparently.
Here is the path that exists: 
C:\Users\skyn\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ug1917fp.default\extensions

and then instead of the next directory in the path, there is an xpi file (with same name):
{a6fd85ed-e919-4a43-a5af-8da18bda539f}.xpi

What happened to the directory and everything in it?

I can't say I understand the way Mozilla organizes its data. Did it install correctly?

Answer (score 3):

This is a issue with the new firefox. It doesn't expand .XPI files automatically.

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Packaging

> Starting in Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4 / Thunderbird 3.3 / SeaMonkey 2.1),
>   XPI files are no longer unpacked when extensions are installed.
>   Instead, the XPI itself is placed in the extensions directory, and
>   files are loaded directly out of the package.

Farther down it says:

> A customized application can include add-ons (including extensions and
>   themes) by placing the unpacked (that is, not the XPI files, but the
>   packages' contents) in the `<appdir>/distribution/bundles` directory.
>   The directory containing the add-on must be named the same as the ID
>   of the add-on or theme. Add-ons packaged in this way will not be
>   visible to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I still don't know how to access the directory inside the XPI in order to store my user-extensions.js file there. This is something standard in SeleniumIDE, so I need to figure out how they expect me to do it.I tried adding my user-extensions.js file to the XPI (since it is just a zip file) but have not gotten it to work yet. Not sure if I am supposed to unzip the XPI or leave it where it is.